# Absolute Value of a Complex Integral

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

My question may seem naive, but I couldn't find its answer in books, websites, etc.

Assume that I want to calculate numerically the absolute value of the following integral

$$I = \int_0^T\exp(if(t)),$$

where $f(t)$ is a real function of $t$.

Which one of the following is the answer?

1. $\quad|I|^2 = I\cdot I^*$
2. $\quad|I|^2 = \displaystyle\int_0^T\mathrm dt\int_0^t\mathrm dt'\exp(-if(t))\exp(if(t'))$

Any comment or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2):

The absolute value of any complex number is given by

$$|a|=\sqrt{a \cdot a^*}$$

It does not matter if you get the value of $a$ by integration, differentiation or another operation. Therefore your first solution is correct.

Your second example introduces a dependency between the integrals, which leads to a wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

1) is True and 2) is almost true, following from 1).

\begin{align}
|I|^2&=I\cdot I^*\\
&=\left(\int_0^T\exp(if(t))dt\right)\left(\int_0^T\exp(-if(t'))dt'\right)\\
&=\int_0^Tdt\int_0^Tdt'\exp(if(t))\exp(-if(t'))
\end{align}
So the only difference is that $\int_0^t$ is replaced by $\int_0^T$.